# Problems with Racket rsound package

Tags: racket

I recently installed (and reinstalled) the rsound Racket package through the Install package... option in the File menu.

Trying to execute

```
#lang racket
(require rsound)
```

I got the following message:

```
ffi-obj: could not find export from foreign library
  name: Pa_GetVersionInfo
  library: C:\Users\danilo\AppData\Roaming\Racket\8.4\pkgs\portaudio-x86_64-win32\portaudio\lib\portaudio.dll
  system error: Impossibile trovare la procedura specificata.; win_err=127
  context...:
   C:\Program Files\Racket\collects\ffi\unsafe.rkt:255:20
   C:\Program Files\Racket\collects\ffi\unsafe.rkt:249:2: get-ffi-obj*
   body of "C:\Users\danilo\AppData\Roaming\Racket\8.4\pkgs\portaudio\portaudio\portaudio.rkt"
   body of top-level
   C:\Program Files\Racket\share\pkgs\xrepl-lib\xrepl\xrepl.rkt:1573:0
   C:\Program Files\Racket\collects\racket\repl.rkt:11:26
```

(The system error message could be translated as "Impossible to find the specified procedure")

I double checked that portaudio.dll and unsafe.rtk were present in their respective directories.  Moreover, typing

```
> raco pkg install rsound
> raco pkg install portaudio
```

gives as output

```
package is already installed
```

in both cases.

Any hints about what's happening?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is a speculative answer but it's too long for a comment.  In summary: almost certainly the Racket libraries are fine, but there is a bug in the portaudio shared library on Windows, and that shared library is included as a dependency of the Racket package.

The best answer is perhaps then to create a ticket on [the GH repo](https://github.com/jbclements/portaudio-x86_64-win32) in the hope that someone will fix it.

### What's wrong with the Racket package on Windows

The portaudio shared library is bundled with the Racket portaudio package, in the form of [portaudio-x86_64-win32](https://github.com/jbclements/portaudio-x86_64-win32).  This library missing the required entry point, and needs to be updated (see below).  There is no clue that I can see as to how that shared library was created: I expect it was copied across from a build or portaudio itself, or perhaps from a release.

### What's wrong with the portaudio shared library on Windows

If you are on Windows, and your portaudio shared library (the thing the Racket portaudio package is linking against) was built with MSVC, and it's too old (specifically, the sources it was built from are more than 11 months old), then `Pa_GetVersionInfo` will be missing.

In particular if you look at the MSVC definitions file for portaudio [here](https://github.com/PortAudio/portaudio/blame/master/msvc/portaudio.def) you'll see that `Pa_GetVersionInfo` was added by [this commit](https://github.com/PortAudio/portaudio/commit/15dfd46b33ae71bdbfa22dd71c37ee7a8e7c659c) which closed [this issue](https://github.com/PortAudio/portaudio/pull/574) as well as a number of related issues, on 27th May 2021.

So if you're using a version built with MSVC from sources older than that, then `Pa_GetVersionInfo` will be missing.  The solution is a more recent version.

Note that the latest (and only) [release](https://github.com/PortAudio/portaudio/releases) is older than this, so if you are using a released version on Windows it probably has this bug.

Comment: Thanks for your timely and detailed answer.  At least I realized that it was not my fault. I spent a couple of hours trying to figure out what was going on.  Now I will try something different (may be the Racket interface to SuperCollider), and that's a pity since rstudio looked so promising..